# Add an new armature object to my rigged object

Tags: rigging

I just bought an Mouth object with an existing armature.
I want to add it to my rigged human, but I can't do it properly. I tried just join it but I broke everything.

I had two object with their rig, I want to keep the mouth and its armature and weights. Also want only one rig.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd> with the armatures but I broke everything, then I tried to parent them, but they keep like two armature, keep separated (Like I need to select body armature or Mouth armature, I want only one).

Do I need to erase the Mouth's armature?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Sorry, we cannot help you because there are too few details in your question. Can you please add more details and a few screenshots? Readers have no idea what the Mouth object, the human model, and the rigs look like (realistic? cartoon? Are the rigs custom rigs? Common rigs? Rigify?) And what have you tried and done? What happened to the human model's mouth? How have you connected the meshes and the rigs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure! I added more details.
I want only one armature, but keep the Mouth's weights and bones